Delphi PasswordChar fires OnExit / OnEnter but only on Panels
I have a Delphi 12.1 VCL app with a password edit field (TEdit with PasswordChar set to *)
I added a "show password" TSpeedButton, but when the password input has focus and I toggle the PasswordChar using the button the OnEnter and OnExit events fire, but only when the TEdit is on a panel. If the TEdit is on the form the events don't fire.
Why do the events fire if the edits are on a panel and not it they are on a form? I would expect them to act the same regardless of the parent?
Example program
TestForm.dfm
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 279
  ClientWidth = 469
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  TextHeight = 15
  object SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton
    Left = 142
    Top = 20
    Width = 23
    Height = 22
    OnClick = SpeedButtonClick
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 195
    Top = 71
    Width = 266
    Height = 200
    ScrollBars = ssBoth
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 4
    Top = 71
    Width = 185
    Height = 66
    TabOrder = 1
    object OnPanelButton: TSpeedButton
      Left = 138
      Top = 17
      Width = 23
      Height = 22
      OnClick = SpeedButtonClick
    end
    object OnPanel: TEdit
      Left = 11
      Top = 13
      Width = 121
      Height = 23
      PasswordChar = '*'
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'OnPanel'
      OnEnter = InputOnEnter
      OnExit = InputOnExit
    end
  end
  object OffPanel: TEdit
    Left = 15
    Top = 24
    Width = 121
    Height = 23
    PasswordChar = '*'
    TabOrder = 2
    Text = 'OffPanel'
    OnEnter = InputOnEnter
    OnExit = InputOnExit
  end
end

TestForm.pas
unit TestForm;

interface

uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
    Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    OnPanel: TEdit;
    OffPanel: TEdit;
    SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;
    OnPanelButton: TSpeedButton;
    procedure SpeedButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure InputOnEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure InputOnExit(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.InputOnEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add((Sender as TEdit).Name + '.OnEnter');
end;

procedure TForm2.InputOnExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add((Sender as TEdit).Name + '.OnExit');
end;

procedure TForm2.SpeedButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    edt: TEdit;
begin
    if Sender = OnPanelButton then
        edt := OnPanel
    else
        edt := OffPanel;

    Memo1.Lines.Add('Swapping PasswordChar on ' + edt.Name);
    if edt.PasswordChar = '*' then
        edt.PasswordChar := #0
    else
        edt.PasswordChar := '*'
end;

end.

Sameple output
OffPanel : TEdit

OffPanel.OnEnter
[button pressed here]
Swapping PasswordChar on OffPanel

OnPanel : TEdit

OnPanel.OnEnter
[button pressed here]
Swapping PasswordChar on OnPanel
OnPanel.OnExit
OnPanel.OnEnter

Edit: I've tried this on Delphi 11 CE installed on a different PC with no extensions / plugins / third part controls etc, with the same results.

Do you have the same problem if you use TButtonedEdit instead?

Yes TButtonedEdit does the same, the edit on the panel fires OnExit / OnEnter. I also noticed that the password is selected when its on a panel and the PasswordChar is changed, but not when its on the form.

This appers to be due to PasswordChar calling RecreateWnd, as replacing the call to PasswordChar with edt.RecreateWnd has the same effect.

That goes back to old annoyances that a lot of VCL properties just recreate HWNDs when they really don't need to. Many HWND styles/features can be updated dynamically without needing to fully recreate the HWND. In this case, the ES_PASSWORD window style can be toggled on/of with SetWindowLongPtr(), or the EM_SETPASSWORCHAR message can be used.

Thanks, I'll give that a try in the morning. Any idea why the events only fire when the edit is on a panel / container control and not when they are placed directly on a form? I would expect the control to act the same regardless. it makes the OnExit / OnEnter events a little unpredictable.

I don't have time to test it myself. But you should be able to enable Debug DCUs in the project settings, and then step into the VCL source code with the debugger, and see what is really happening for yourself.

Thanks to @RemyLebeau pointing me in the right direction, I was able to figure out what was happening. I'll put my findings below for anyone else experiencing the same issue.
This only affects Delphi 11/12, but not Delphi 2007, I am unsure about versions in between.
When PasswordChar is changed, Delphi calls RecreateWnd() (there are other properties that also call RecreateWnd() when changed).
RecreateWnd() sends a message to CMRecreateWnd(), this in turn destroys and recreates the control's window, checking if it was focused first so the focus can be restored after recreation.
When the control's window is destroyed, Delphi tries to give the parent focus, using the TCustomForm.SetFocusedControl() function.
If SetFocusedControl() finds a control to give focus to, it will fire the OnExit event of the control whose window is being destroyed, and then sets the Screen.ActiveControl to the parent control.
When the control's window is recreated, focus is returned to it, and its OnEnter fires.
So, in my case, the TEdit's window was destroyed and focus was given temporarily to the parent TPanel.
So, why does this only happen when the control is on a container and not placed directly on a TForm?
One of the first lines of code in SetFocusedControl() looks like this:
if Control <> Self then
  FActiveControl := Control else
  FActiveControl := nil;

I'm not 100% sure why, but this appears to stop the events being fired if the Control being given focus is a Form.
Remy's solution to fix this using window messages works well. The other solution that may work is to temporally unhook the events, change the property, then re-attach the events.

"This only affects Delphi 11/12, but not Delphi 2007" - I would expect earlier versions to be affected as well, as they do the same steps you described.
